# Head movement detection using 1 accelerometer

Tags: accelerometer

I've been assigned a small project of designing a turning jacket for cyclist, which is used to indicate when the cyclist turns right or left using LEDs attached to the back of the jacket. I plan to use 1 accelerometer to detect the head movement. There are simply two kinds of movement: left and right. Is it possible to use 1 accelerometer to specify the movement of the head?

Thanks!

Comment: But a cyclist *looks* left and right a lot more often than they turn corners. And an indicator is to show other people your *intent* to turn, before you turn, so that other people can allow for it. Won't those make a head-turn based system unworkable?